# Cheapest Metro/RER ticket in Paris

Tags: public-transport

I will be staying 10 days in Paris with a day visit into Zone 5.  What is the best public transport ticket: Navigo Decouverte OR Origin/Destination OR T+  ?

Comment: I chose Navigo Decouverte in 2015 for a week stay with a trip to Le Bourget. Keep in mind that Navigo Decouverte is valid for a given week (from Monday to Sunday). You can ask for an extension ticket to your destination/Paris (_complement de parcours_)

Answer (score 3):

If you only have one journey into zone 5, the cheaper alternative is to buy a *Origine-Destination* ticket for that journey.

To decide wether for the everyday travels you are better buying *T+* tickets or a *Paris Visite* depends on how many different travels you expect to do daily and how they are done (see http://www.ratp.fr/en/ratp/r_61656/t-ticket/ for the rules that apply for connections with *T+*). Keep in mind that *T+* is only valid for zone 1-2.

If you buy *T+* tickets by 10, if you expect to use more than 25 tickets on 5 days, you're cheaper buying a zone 1-3 5 days *Paris Visite*.